# How to insert int in app.EnterText()?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, automated-tests, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to insert a number in a numeric field using app.EnterText(VALUE) but i'm getting this error:

> Exception: System.Exception: Underlying query failed with output: 
>   {"status_bar_orientation":"down","results":[{"status":"error","value":"Input: uia.typeString('50')\n. Error: VerboseError: Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().keyboard()  typeString@[native code]\nkeyboard_enter_text__delegate@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:26635:66\nkeyboard_enter_text@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:26643:46\napply_to@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:10922:22\napply__2@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:11126:39\napply@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:11219:29\ntypeString__delegate@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:28133:64\ntypeString@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:28140:37\neval code\neval@[native code]\nglobal code@file://localhost/tmp/run_loop20171030-2474-f8p0nc/_run_loop.js:28602:35","index":221}],"outcome":"SUCCESS"}
>     at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSGestures.ValidateSuccessfulCalabashResult (Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpResult result) [0x00021] in <0d617a84142b49c5bfa7670d2eeb5494>:0 
>     at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSGestures.EnterText (Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Queries.SingleQuoteEscapedString text) [0x00069] in <0d617a84142b49c5bfa7670d2eeb5494>:0 
>     at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp+c__AnonStorey6.<>m__0 () [0x00194] in <0d617a84142b49c5bfa7670d2eeb5494>:0 
>     at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With (System.Action func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x00006] in <0d617a84142b49c5bfa7670d2eeb5494>:0 
>   FTook final screenshot. { Title: "After test", FileName: "/Volumes/Data/xamarin/workspaces/b566c470-cb84-4bf6-a4aa-a328396a2e3f/workspace/screenshot-final-c8f3657d9b934652b8d54d234d597041.png", ElapsedMilliseconds: 2820 }

The value is a string but if i change it to int i can't execute.

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions :

1 : Usually the best one, you specify the field class or id where you want to write

```
app.EnterText("CLASS_OR_ID", "VALUE");
```

2 : First you select the field and then you write in it

```
app.Tap("CLASS_OR_ID");
app.EnterText("VALUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify where you are entering the ***VALUE*** into.

For example, try:

```
app.EnterText(c=>c.Id("ElementID"), VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (if the element is a text field) is to:

```
app.EnterText(c => c.TextField("TextFieldID"), "Text that you want entered into TextFieldID ");
```

TextField (for Android): An element that has class Android.Widget.EditText

TextField (for iOS): An element with class UITextField